# What is meaning of ##*/ in unix?

Tags: unix

I found syntax like below.

```
${VARIABLE##*/}
```

what is the meaning of `##*/` in this?

I know meaning of `*/` in `ls */` but not aware about what above syntax does.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix usage, belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523512/what-does-mean-inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example will make it clear:

```
VARIABLE='abcd/def/123'

echo "${VARIABLE#*/}"
def/123

echo "${VARIABLE##*/}"
123
```

- `##*/` is stripping out **longest match** of *anything followed by* `/` from **start of input**.
- `#*/` is stripping out **shortest match** of *anything followed by* `/` from **start of input**.

**PS:** Using all capital variable names is not considered very good practice in Unix shell. Better to use `variable` instead of `VARIABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

From `man bash`:

```
   ${parameter#word}
   ${parameter##word}
          Remove matching prefix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce
          a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches
          the beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of  the
          expansion  is  the expanded value of parameter with the shortest
          matching pattern (the ``#'' case) or the longest  matching  pat‐
          tern  (the  ``##''  case)  deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the
          pattern removal operation is applied to each positional  parame‐
          ter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If param‐
          eter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *,  the  pattern
          removal  operation  is  applied  to  each member of the array in
          turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
```